# serialize data from javascript to php has an error when passing &

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to convert form data to serialize and sending it to php:

I'm using summernote to convert html to text:

```
var str = $('#description').summernote('code');
var formData =  $('#form').serialize();
var formData2=formData+'&data='+str;
```

and data has one parameter with the value including `&nbsp` which pops up an error as `&` is included. How can I pass the same value to php?

```
&name=title_name&data=<p>TL/DR: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae vestibulum dui. Donec non diam eget quam consectetur rhoncus at et purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse placerat accumsan orci ac hendrerit. Donec porttitor, tortor sed laoreet aliquam, libero urna lacinia lorem, laoreet euismod urna felis tincidunt nunc. Nam posuere massa quam, at ultrices est sollicitudin vel.!</p><p><br></p><p> Lorem ipsum?&nbsp;</p><p><br>Lorem ipsum</p><p>
```

Comment: if this isn't a php-related issue, the tag should be removed, since there is no code to support it, as it makes the question unclear.

Comment: can you show full code please? :)

Comment: I've updated the code. CHeck it out. I'm using summernote to convert text to html

Comment: `var formData2=formData+'&data='+encodeURIComponent(str);`

Comment: I tried doing this 
          var formData2=encodeURIComponent(formData)+'&data='+encodeURIComponent(str);  I've tried decoding this on php but I'm getting index not found. How can I decode it ?

Comment: Also, please answer it below. I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: `formData` is alread encoded by jquery, so you only need to encode the data you are grabbing manually from the wysiwyg, as i show in the comment. Did you try that?

Comment: @Steve PLease write your answer below so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @jason OK, have done

Comment: @Steve Accepted!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, jqwuery's `serialize()` function urlencodes the form fields as part of the process.

Since you are manually appending data to the result, you will need to do the same with that data:

```
var formData2 = formData + '&data=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
```